# Visual Studio [copy properties]

Tags: windows, visual-studio, properties

Is there any way to copy the whole properties of a project to another one? (in any version of Visual Studios)

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the design-generated code in formname.Designer.cs (.cs for C#), copy that to your new projects designer.cs and replace the names.

It's under the region named "Windows Form Designer generated code"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using C++. I had to mention this before !